# store procedure mysql cant run in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure in mysql when i want call it in codeigniter, cant be run and nothing display error message, this my code:
**in my Models:**

```
<?php

function insertlat_2() {
    $sql = $this->db->query("call jmllatihan()");
    return $sql->result();
}
?>
```

**and This My COntroller:**

```
<?php

function addlat() {
    $data['pemain'] = $this->m_user->getpemain();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $tgl_latihan = $this->input->post('tgl');
        $data = array('id_pemain' => $_POST['pemain'],
            'k_atas' => $_POST['k_atas'],
            'k_datar' => $_POST['k_datar'],
            'p_dasar' => $_POST['p_dasar'],
            'p_atas' => $_POST['p_atas'],
            'h_statis' => $_POST['h_statis'],
            'h_atas' => $_POST['h_lompat'],
            'lari_12' => $_POST['a_12'],
            'lari_30' => $_POST['a_30'],
            's_cdatar' => $_POST['s_cdatar'],
            's_catas' => $_POST['s_catas'],
            's_terarah' => $_POST['s_tarah'],
            'd_lurus' => $_POST['a_dlurus'],
            'd_zigzag' => $_POST['a_dzig'],
            'free_style' => $_POST['freestyle'],
            't_clear' => $_POST['t_clear'],
            't_total' => $_POST['t_total'],
            'time' => $tgl_latihan);
        $this->db->insert('latihan_1', $data);
        $this->m_user->insertlat_2();
        redirect('menu/addlat', 'refresh');
    } else {
        // $data['record']=$this->db->get_where('kriteria', array('id_pemain' =>0))->result();            
        $this->template->display('menu/latihan', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

**and this my procedure:**
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZsPV.png)

Please Help me...

Comment: What is `jmllatihan()` doing? - Should it return something ?- even though your code doesn't make any sense because you are returning a result without processing it - you should post your mysql function here...

Comment: will you show your procedure? What actually it does?

Comment: sory i should upload my procedure by image, because character its too long

Comment: But when I call the procedure directly in MySQL, It works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

First, modify application/config/config.php, line 55.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; // USE mysqli
```

Comment: But when I call the procedure directly in MySQL, It works

Comment: Please do not post multiple answers containing your guesses. If you want to update an answer, [edit] it. I've deleted your other answer.